# Why arrays.splice() function does not remove the element?

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-splice

I have a strange behaviour with the splice() function.

Suppose that this is the array:

```
var arrObj = [{"key1":"val1"},{"key2":"val2"}];
```

If I make from the browser console:

```
arrObj.splice(0,1);
```

The first element is removed as expected.

But if I make this operation in a function, the splice doesn't make any change to the array!

How is possible?

EDIT

```
var index = undefined;
for (var i=0; i<arrObj.length; i++) {
    if (arrObj[i].key1 == "key1"){
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}
if (index != undefined) 
    arrObj.splice[index,1];  // this doesn't work!
```

Comment: sorry, is not the error, copy-past problem

Comment: you can use `indexOf()` instead of `for` loop.

Comment: Yeah Satpal, you are right! Sorry, I didn't realized that there was [] instead of () ...

Comment: None of your objects have a `.key` property.  `arrObj[i].key` will *always* be undefined

Comment: splice is a function not an object.

Comment: @gurvinder372, you did not accept an answer yet. Could you accept the one that best answered to your needs? Does not have to be mine, but you should accept one, unless the question is not fully answered of course, but then you should leave a comment about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correcting yourself. You are using `[]` intead of `()` in this line:

```
arrObj.splice[index,1];
```

You should put

```
arrObj.splice(index,1);
```

Comment: Yeah, exactly... I didn't realized that... thanks for the eye!

Answer (score 3):

Your `index` is undefined, because `arrObj` doesn't have `key` property

```
if (arrObj[i].key == "key1") {
    index = i;
    break;
}
```

Change to this

```
if (arrObj[i].key1) {
    index = i;
    break;
}
```

#### Working example

```js
var arrObj = [{ "key1": "val1" }, { "key2": "val2" }];
var index = undefined;

for (var i = 0; i < arrObj.length; i++) {
    if (arrObj[i].key1) {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}

if (index != undefined)
    arrObj.splice(index, 1);

document.write(JSON.stringify(arrObj));
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem is this line

```
if (arrObj[i].key == "key1"){
```

Replace it with

```
if (Object.keys(arrObj[i])[0] == "key1"){
```

since none of the objects in the array has `key` as key/property.

Complete code with **DEMO** below

```js
var arrObj = [{"key1":"val1"},{"key2":"val2"}];
var index = undefined;
for (var i=0; i<arrObj.length; i++) {
    if (Object.keys(arrObj[i])[0] == "key1"){
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}
if (index != undefined) 
    arrObj.splice(index,1); 

document.body.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(arrObj,0,4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

1. syntax:

   ```
    arrObj.splice[index,1];
   ```

   should have parentheses (for function call) instead of brackets (for object property):

   ```
    arrObj.splice(index,1);
   ```
2. `key` is not a key in any of your array elements:

   ```
   if (arrObj[i].key == "key1"){
   ```

   should better be  written as:

   ```
   if (arrObj[i]["key1"] !== undefined){
   ```

But you can write all this much more elegantly like this:

```
arrObj = arrObj.filter(function (el) {
    return el["key1"] === undefined;
});
```

Or with EcmaScript 2015 syntax:

```
arrObj = arrObj.filter((el) => el["key1"] === undefined);
```

Note that this will remove all elements that have "key1" as a property, not only the first one.

If you want, you can turn this into a function like this, illustrated with a functional snippet:

```js
function removeByKey(arrObj, key) {
    return arrObj.filter(function (el) { return el[key] === undefined; });
}

// Sample data:
arrObj = [{"key1":"val1"},{"key2":"val2"}];

// Output original array
document.write('before: ' + JSON.stringify(arrObj) + '<br>');

// Call function
arrObj = removeByKey(arrObj, "key1");

// Output resulting array
document.write('after: ' + JSON.stringify(arrObj));
```